# Why am I unable to get WebGL?

Tags: radeon, asus, webgl

So I've been trying all day to get WebGL running on my Ubuntu 13.10 system, to no avail. Here is the output of my chrome://gpu page in the latest Google Chrome:

http://jsbin.com/eRoledI/1/

I've tried downloading and running the latest ATI Catalyst (which kills my display entirely, giving me a black screen and cursor).  I've also tried enabling the propriatery drivers in the system settings.  I've also disabled "Use hardware acceleration when available" in Chrome, [as suggested](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1220892).

I bought my Radeon HD 6450 this week, so it should be able to cope.  It [does seem to be compatible with WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists#Chrome_on_Linux), but how can I tell if the drivers in use are greater than ["AMD drivers 8.98"](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/BlacklistsAndWhitelists#Chrome_on_Linux) - [here is the info available to me](http://i.imm.io/1iLr6.png).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to start Chrome/Chromium in a terminal using `chromium-browser --enable-webgl --ignore-gpu-blacklist` (replace `chromium-browser` with the name of Chrome executable) and check again `chrome://gpu`.